# CriteriaBuilder: Create Criteria based on DataType at runtime

Tags: java, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I have a simplified `Entity` class like this:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    String name;
    Date birthday;
    Integer term;
}
```

A third party dependency (DataTables) is sending a search request in form of a `Map<String,String>` where the `key` is the name of the entity's attribut  and the `value` the search `String`. A map can look like this:

```
key      |   value
------------------
name     |   Alice
birthday |    2000
term     |       3
```

I currently use this implementation, which works fine for `String` attributes like `name`:

```
public List<Student> getStudents(Map<String,String> filters) throws Exception {
    //get builder
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
    Root<Student> student = cq.from(Student.class);

    //validate if attribut exists
    try {
        for(String key : filters.keySet()) {
            student.get(key); //check if path exists
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException ex ) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid filter parameters!");
    }

    // select
    cq.select(student);
    //where
    Predicate wherePredicate = cb.and(); // init with true;
    for (Entry<String,String> filter : filters.entrySet()) {
        wherePredicate = cb.and(wherePredicate,
                                cb.like(student.get(filter.getKey()), "%"+filter.getValue()+"%"));
    }           
    cq.where(wherePredicate);

    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

}

Of course, the `like` criteria does not work for `Integer` or `Date`. **How can I extent my code to define criterias based on the attributes data type?**

I tried this, what unfortuantly is not possible in Java:

```
switch (student.get(filter.getKey()).getClass()) {
    case Path<String>.class:
         return cb.like(student.get(filter.getKey()), "%"+filter.getValue()+"%");
    case Path<Integer>.class:
         return cb.equal(student.get(filter.getKey()), filter.getValue())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best approach, but you can use just simple name of the class:

```
String className= student.get(filter.getKey()).getClass().getSimpleName();
switch (className) {
   case "Integer":
       return cb.equal(student.get(filter.getKey()), filter.getValue())
   case "String":
       return cb.like(student.get(filter.getKey()), "%"+filter.getValue()+"%");
}
```

Comment: `getSimpleName()` returns **SingularAttributePath** and not the generic value `<T>`

Comment: @Thanthla What returns pdat.get(filter.getKey())? For String, Integer and Date filter?

Comment: It returns an Object of type Path<T>, where T is the data type of the student's attribut.

Comment: @Thanthla could you, please send the implementation of the method student.get()? 
Is this method used somewhere else?

Comment: `Root<Student> student = cq.from(Student.class);` is a class from the CriteriaBuilder. `student.get(...)` returns the path to the attribut. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#get(javax.persistence.metamodel.MapAttribute)